# Merge two Changesets, Get Latest, CheckIn in TFS Programatically

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, tfs

I searched a lot to get Merge two changesets, then get latest of the target branch and then checkin the target branch. I am using a ajax to call a method named `MergeChangeSets` by passing `sourceBranch`, `targetBranch`, `changeset[]`.
Method is as follows.

```cs
public void MergeChangeSets(string pSourceBranch, string pDestinationBranch, string[] pChangeSet)
{
    var serverpath= "http://10.201.1.7:8081/tfs/";
}
```

Please help... It's been days I'm sitting behind this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find solution for all these questions here step by step. Just copy past it. Itz working.

http://teamfoundation.blogspot.com/2006/11/merging-and-resolving-conflicts-using.html